# Transaction in entity framework in N-Tier Architecture

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

How to make transaction statement to insert data into database using Entity Framework Core. I am using N-tier architecture in my project.

I am able to save data in multiple table separately but unable to do so using EF transaction.

Kindly help me to achieve this.

```
public IActionResult CreateUpdate(VM_tVchMst vm, IFormFile? file)
{           
    try
    {
        string FileName = string.Empty;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (vm.vchMst.VchId == 0)
            {
                VchNoGeneration vchNo = new VchNoGeneration();
                string vchNoGenCode = vchNo.fnSysVchNo("10", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), DateTime.Now.ToString("MM"), vm.vchMst.VchType);
                vm.vchMst.VchNo = vchNoGenCode;

                _unitOfWork.JournalVoucherMst.add(vm.vchMst);
                _unitOfWork.Save();

                vm.vchDtls = vchDtls;

                foreach (var item in vm.vchDtls)
                {
                    long Srno = item.VchdtlId;
                    string Ledger = item.Ledger;
                    item.VchdtlId = 0;
                    item.VchId = vm.vchMst.VchId;

                    _unitOfWork.JournalVoucherDtl.add(item);
                    _unitOfWork.Save();

                    vm.vchDtl = _unitOfWork.JournalVoucherDtl.GetT(x => x.VchId == vm.vchMst.VchId && x.Ledger == Ledger);
                    vm.vchLdgrRefs = vchLdgrRefs;

                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        foreach (var itemref in vm.vchLdgrRefs)
                        {
                            if (itemref.VchDtlId == Srno)
                            {
                                itemref.VchDtlId = vm.vchDtl.VchdtlId;

                                _unitOfWork.JournalVoucherRef.add(itemref);
                                _unitOfWork.Save();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    vm.vchLdgrCosts = vchLdgrCosts;

                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        foreach (var itemcost in vm.vchLdgrCosts)
                        {
                            if (itemcost.VchDtlId == Srno)
                            {
                                itemcost.VchDtlId = vm.vchDtl.VchdtlId;

                                _unitOfWork.JournalVoucherCost.add(itemcost);
                                _unitOfWork.Save();
                            }
                        }
                    }                            
                }                       

                TempData["success"] = "Journal Voucher Created Successfully!";
            }                  

            _unitOfWork.Save();

            return RedirectToAction("CreateUpdate");
        }

        return RedirectToAction("CreateUpdate");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        TempData["Error"] = ex.Message;
        return RedirectToAction("CreateUpdate");
    }
}
```

Actually i don't understand that how we can use transaction command with commit for multiple save in my query...

Comment: Well, what happens? Do you get an error?